# Standard notation for the transform that turns a function $A \rightarrow (B \rightarrow C)$ into a function $B \rightarrow (A \rightarrow C).$

Tags: functions, notation, category-theory, computer-science

Suppose we're given sets $A,B$ and $C$. Then to each function $f : A \rightarrow (B \rightarrow C)$, we can assign another function $F : B \rightarrow (A \rightarrow C)$ by defining:

$$F(b)(a) = f(a)(b)$$

> **Question.** Is there standard notation for $F$, like $[f]$ or $\# f$ or
>   something?

This is motivated by my question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1390700/in-differential-geometry-is-there-established-notation-for-the-stuff-that-mat); see the edit at the end of that question.

Comment: In Computer Science this function is usually called `flip`, e.g. see [here](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=flip), but I doubt  you can use it without definition.

Comment: @dtldarek, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By request, making a comment into an answer.

In Computer Science this function is usually called `flip`, e.g., see [here](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=flip).

However, it is not that well known, and I would advise you to define it before usage, for example:

\begin{align}
&\mathtt{flip}(f)(x)(y) &&= f(y)(x) &\text{classic style}\\
&\mathtt{flip}(f) &&= x \mapsto \big(y \mapsto f(y)(x)\big) &\text{'maps-to' style}\\
&\mathtt{flip} &&= \lambda f.\ \lambda x.\ \lambda y.\ f\ y\ x &\text{$\lambda$-calculus style}\\
&\mathtt{flip}\ f\ x\ y &&= f\ y\ x &\text{functional programming style}
\end{align}

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$

Answer (score 1):

Well, besides $\operatorname{flip}$ there is $\operatorname{swap}$. This is the name used in the [homotopy type theory book](https://homotopytypetheory.org/book/) (see 1.4 and don't get confused by the dependent function types; it does what you want).